# After saving file in s3 via boto3, it is being downloaded instead of being viewed

Tags: amazon-s3, flask, boto3

I am saving some html content to Amazon s3, from my flask api using boto3 module with the code

**s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, PREFIX + file_name+'.html').put(Body=html_content)**

The file is being stored in s3 but when I am going to view it it is just getting downloaded instead of being viewed. I would rather try to view the file instead of downloading it. How to fix it from boto3 commands? Kindly help me.

Comment: You need to set content-disposition header to inline. It's default value is attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the S3 bucket and browse to the file > properties > metadata, there is a key called Content-Type that tells AWS what kind of content it is, it's probably set to binary so it will only be downloaded at the moment, like in this screenshot:

[image: metadata screenshot]

If you change this value to "text/plain" for example it will attempt to view it.

Comment: Thanks. It solves the problem. It was really helpful.